# EDIT: Tensorflow memory issues, but works fine with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My code gets stuck when calling `sess.run(init)`.

I tried to look it up, and I tried a few possible solutions... still can't get beyond `sess.run(init)`.

Do anyone have a suggestion? My first thought is that something is wrong with the definition of the network. Code is simplified.

**EDIT:** Thanks @pop and @gdelab the problem was narrowed down to a memory issue. *BUT* the network works fine when I use TF+Keras.

Maybe its a network definition problem in the TF only code? My task is to convert the TF + Keras script to a TF only script.

**This is the code with only TF:**

```
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="SAME")

def weight_variable(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))

def bias_variabel(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape))

def sig2d(x):
    return tf.nn.sigmoid(x, name='Sigmoid-normalization')


  import tensorflow as tf

  tf.reset_default_graph()
  sess = tf.Session()

  xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 153600])
  x_image = tf.reshape(xs, [-1, 160, 320, 3])
  ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

  x_image = tf.nn.sigmoid(x_image)

  W_conv1 = weight_variable([4,4,3,16])  
  b_conv1 = bias_variabel([16])
  h_conv1 = tf.nn.elu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

  W_conv2 = weight_variable([5,5,16,32])
  b_conv2 = bias_variabel([32])
  h_conv2 = tf.nn.elu(conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

  W_conv3 = weight_variable([5,5,32,64])
  b_conv3 = bias_variabel([64])
  h_conv3 = tf.nn.elu(conv2d(h_conv2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)

  flat1 = tf.reshape(h_conv3, [-1, 160*320*64])
  drop1 = tf.nn.dropout(flat1, 0.2)
  elu1 = tf.nn.elu(drop1)
  dense1 = tf.layers.dense(elu1, 512)
  drop2 = tf.nn.dropout(dense1, 0.5)
  elu2 = tf.nn.elu(drop2)
  output = tf.layers.dense(elu2, 1)

  loss = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(ys, output))))

  gs=tf.train.get_global_step()
  train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss,global_step=gs)

  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  sess.run(init) # STUCK

  for i in range(2000):
      batch_xs, batch_ys = next(gen(20, args.host, port=args.port))
      batch_xs = np.reshape(batch_xs,(-1,153600))
      sess.run(train, feed_dict={xs: batch_xs, ys: batch_ys})
```

**This is the code with TF + Keras:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Lambda, ELU
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D
from keras.utils import plot_model

def gen(hwm, host, port):
  for tup in client_generator(hwm=hwm, host=host, port=port):
    X, Y, _ = tup
    Y = Y[:, -1]
    if X.shape[1] == 1:  # no temporal context
      X = X[:, -1]
    yield X, Y


def get_model(time_len=1):
  ch, row, col = 3, 160, 320  # camera format

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5 - 1., # Normalize data from -1 to 1
            input_shape=(ch, row, col),
            output_shape=(ch, row, col)))
  model.add(Convolution2D(16, 8, 8, subsample=(4, 4), border_mode="same"))
  model.add(ELU())
  model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode="same"))
  model.add(ELU())
  model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode="same"))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dropout(.2))
  model.add(ELU())
  model.add(Dense(512))
  model.add(Dropout(.5))
  model.add(ELU())
  model.add(Dense(1))

  model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")

  return model

if __name__ == "__main__":

  tf.reset_default_graph()
  sess = tf.Session()

  model = get_model()

  model.fit_generator(
    gen(20, args.host, port=args.port),
    samples_per_epoch=10000,
    nb_epoch=args.epoch,
    validation_data=gen(20, args.host, port=args.val_port),
    nb_val_samples=1000
  )

  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  sess.run(init)
```

Comment: show us also where init is defined, and the line that causes a problem... We may need weight_variable() and bias_variable() also

Comment: init is defined in the code right before the for-loop, sess.run(init) is also there. I added the other functions.

Comment: Sorry I had not seen. Anyway that's quite unusual: for me something sends a SIGKILL during sess.run(init) after a few seconds...

Comment: It seems it is because of the size of the tensors you create. If I replace `153600` by say `50` and `160` & `320` by `10` in your code, initialization works

Comment: Yep same for me, reducing the data size worked, it must be only a memory issue

Comment: @Pop Ok, smaller data size, but still not entirely sure what you ment. What do you suggest changing this to:   `xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,153600])` ?

Comment: @NorwegianClassic See my asnwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a memory problem: the matrix for the 1st dense layer is too big: `160*320*64*512 ~ 1.7e9` elements => around `7GB` for this layer alone ! You need to reduce the size, with `max_pool`ings in the network for instance.

In practice it works if you change 512 to 1 for instance, or if you reduce the input image size (it worked with 16*16 for me for instance, didn't try bigger)

Comment: I see. This is actually a project done with tf+keras: [link](https://github.com/commaai/research/blob/master/train_steering_model.py) I have run this code before, and everything worked well. Now I'm trying to rewrite this code without Keras, and  now suddenly there is a memory issue. Any suggestions on why this worked with Keras, and not without?

Comment: @NorwegianClassic It's because of `subsample=(4, 4)` (or other values, depending on the layer): in keras you're using a stride bigger than (1, 1) in your convolution, which effetively reduces the image size at each convolution step, while in TF you don't. You need to `add strides=[1, 4, 4, 1]` (or [1, 2, 2, 1] depending on the layer) in your conv2d arguments

Comment: By the way it looks like your first convolution does not have the same kernel size in both versions (4x4 vs 8x8)

Comment: Ah man you are totally right, thank you! I also hadde to change the input size of the flatten layer, but now everything worked!

Comment: For the flatten layer you could just take the size values from `h_conv3.get_shape().as_list()`, it would avoid mistakes when you change the input size or the strides. Glad I could help !

Comment: That's a good idea, unfortunately I am having problems using it. I get this when I use it:  `TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <type 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 10, 20, 64]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.` I tried `tf.convert_to_tensor()` but didnt work. Did you mean something else or did I use it wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you've written, but this works: 

`h_conv3 = tf.nn.elu(conv2d(h_conv2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)

    shape = h_conv3.get_shape().as_list()
    flat1 = tf.reshape(h_conv3, [-1, shape[1]*shape[2]* shape[3]])`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is only because of the size of the tensors you create.
If I replace `153600` by say `50`, it works normally...
So, this must be a memory issue.

You need to decrease the size of some of your variables (or use more RAM, if this is an option). You could do mean or max pooling between your convolutional layers for example. So that, the `output` tensor becomes smaller and fits in your memory

Comment: I see. This is actually a project done with tf+keras: [link](https://github.com/commaai/research/blob/master/train_steering_model.py) I have run this code before, and everything worked well. Now I'm trying to rewrite this code without Keras, and  now suddenly there is a memory issue. Any suggestions on why this worked with Keras, and not without?

Comment: No, I am not aware enough of what's under the hood in Keras. Maybe you could post your keras implementation as an edit to the question